# Why does connecting to SMB share also use wsman

Tags: windows, server-message-block, winrm

When I connect to a file share using \servername\share in Windows explorer (windows 10 to a windows server share), I notice that there are also connections from my host to the destination server over port 5985, the wsman protocol port.

I couldn't find any obvious information on why this would happen. Anyone got any clue as to why this would occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an answer as to "why", but here's a forum post by someone that shows that SMB3 connections from Win10 will also attempt to connect via wsman.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/a-windows-10-client-accessing-a-smb3-file-share/98e3d0ed-89da-40c1-b68c-553bf9999550

From doing some more reading around, it seems like this might be from server-management features on the client; like if you have RSAT installed on it, it may attempt to connect via WS-MAn (PS Remoting).

Is that the case? What version(s) are your Win10 clients and fileservers? What process on the client is using TCP 5985; is it explorer.exe or something else?

What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I think RSAT is the bingo here, as that is installed on my client. I was mainly trying to understand the behavior as I noticed it in a SIEM. Thank you.